How to prevent a function to be called within composable functions?
Is there a way to only allow a function be to called within non-composable functions?
Some context:
In our project, we have a custom alert (compose material ui) implemented with AbstractComposeView.
With below extension method, we can show compose alerts in activity/fragment directly.
fun Activity.alert(dialogData: AlertDialogData) {
  AlertDialogComposeView(this).show(dialogData) // which adds AlertDialogComposeView to this activity using `addContentView(..)`
}

However, when used directly within composable functions, a new composeView gets added for every composition.
So we have to wrap it within a LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) { activity.alert(..) } to alert ONCE when enters composition.
We want to make sure that it never gets called directly within a composable function.
It would be good to have a custom annotation, e.g. @NotComposable
Or is there a way to check if current function is being called within composable functions?

You can define a custom annotation and check for it's usage with runtime checks. It Worked well for me in java but I am not sure if it will work for Kotlin. The process is very simple:

Make a custom annotation.
Put the annotation.
Do runtime checks.

The runtime checks should look something like this:
public static void checkNotInComposableContext() {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTrace) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(element.getClassName());
            for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (method.getName().equals(element.getMethodName())) {
                    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(NotComposable.class)) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Method cannot be called.");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // error
        }
    }
}

Let me know if it works.

Hi Sohan, thanks for your input.
I dont think analyzing the whole stack trace with reflections is a good idea.
I did give it a try: I attempted to get the most recent method invocation  and check if it has @Composable annotation but it did not work.
I'm more inclined now to create custom android lint to achieve this.

They only need to be defined outside of a class if you plan on using the @Preview annotation.
You cannot access this compose function in outside compose file.
